# update datagridview when row is added

Tags: c#, datagridview, row

I have a list that I bind to datagridview like this:

```
      SyncList<MyClass> myList = new SyncList<MyClass>();
      dataGridView1.DataSource = myList;
```

When I update MyList, datagrid updates smoothly, but when I add a new row, nothing happens unless I reassign DataSource again. How can I make it so that datagridview shows new rows and doesn't reset scrollbar. Thanks

Comment: you have to update the datasource to the grid in order to reflect the changes.

Comment: @saravanan do you mean I have to re-assign DateSource again to reflect changes when adding new rows? thanks

Comment: yes. using the grid in an update panel or call the `dataset.AcceptChanges()` and then call `gridview.DataBind()`.